# How to save two copies of the same image in a wordpress upload?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, wordpress-theming

So here's what I'm trying to do, basically when the users upload a new image, I want to make an image half that size (keeping the proportion) and half the resolution, but save both versions. Maybe save the original as 'image-upload.jpg' and the one I modify using php save it as 'image-upload-halved.jpg'

I've messed around with wordpress filters, but can't seem to get it. Below is along the lines of what I was thinking I should do, but I really have no idea.

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'custom_upload_filter' );

function custom_upload_filter( $file ){
    // here I was hoping I could do the image manipulation
    // and also save both versions of the image
}
```

Any advice or links to other wordpress filters that might fit the job better would be awesome, too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the documentation for `add_image_size` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

You should be able to add a new image size like this:

```
add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 180 ); // 220 pixels wide by 180 pixels tall, soft proportional crop mode
```

Replace "custom-size" with a name for your size and the pixel values that you want.

You can call the image in your template like this:

```
// Assuming your Media Library image has a post id of 42...
echo wp_get_attachment_image( 42, 'your-custom-size' );
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I'm looking for. I do not want a 'fixed' crop size. I want to be able to cut in half the resolution and size of the image dynamically. For example, if a user uploads:

400x400 original image = new image is 200x200
800x600 original image = new image 400x300 

But then, be able to save both the original image as well as the new image.